# Integrating quotients with polynomials in numerator and denominator that are raised to fractional powers

Tags: integration, trigonometry, polynomials, exponentiation, quotient-spaces

I'm working through a paper on momentum in electrodynamics that requires the integration below and would greatly appreciate any help. I'm pretty sure it evaluates to $2/d$ but I can't quite figure how.

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}
{r^{4}\sin^{3}\left(\theta\right)
\over
\left\{(r^{2} + d^{2}/4)^2 - \left[rd\cos\left(\theta\right)\right]^{2}\right\}^{3/2}}
\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta  \space-[1]
$$

If I focus on the integration w.r.t. r first, I get [2]. If I focus on the integration w.r.t. $\theta$ first, I get [3]. A,B,C are just constants w.r.t. the variable of integration.

I believe I can make a series of substitutions but they don't seem to get me closer to an answer.

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} {Ar^{4}
\over
\left[(r^{2} + B)^2 -\left(rC\right)^{2}\right]^{3/2}}\,{\rm d}r   \space-[2]
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}
{A\sin^{3}\left(\theta\right)
\over
\left\{(C)^2 - \left[B\cos\left(\theta\right)\right]^{2}\right\}^{3/2}}
\,{\rm \rm d}\theta  \space-[3]
$$

Comment: If you are concerned with units, your dimensions do not match in the denominator.

Comment: Units are always important. Thanks for pointing that out! I have fixed the equations.

Comment: What are $A, B, C$ supposed to be?

Comment: A,B,C would be constant w.r.t. r. Specifically,$ A = \sin^3 \theta, B = \frac {d^2}{4}, X = (d)(\cos \theta) $

Comment: After some thought and research, I believe a trig substitution will help but I am still not close to an answer.